# Detrending data

Tags: r, regression, time-series, trend

```
  dat <- structure(list(year = c(1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
                                 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), 
                        yield = c(1436.98, 1921.98, 1619.99, 1799.93, 2100, 1832.96, 2208.01, 2399.99, 2200.01, 2699.96, 2700, 2700.08, 
                                  2699.99, 2940.02, 3119.97, 2639.99, 2460, 2880, 2700, 3000, 3120, 
                                  3000, 3059.98, 3300, 3180, 2820, 3240, 3060, 2400)), 
                        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -29L))
  with(dat, plot(year, yield, type = "b", pch = 19))
```

[image]

This data is crop yield across number of years for a given location. I am interested in detrending the data and use the detrended data in a regression. This is how I am detrending it:

```
  mod.lm <- lm(yield ~ year, data = dat)
  mod.lm2 <- lm(yield ~ poly(year, 2), data = dat)
  anova(mod.lm, mod.lm2)
```

The result suggests that a quadratic model is better.

```
  dat$detrended.data <- resid(mod.lm2)
  plot(dat$year, dat$detrended.data, ylim = c(-500 , 500))
```

[image]

use the detrended data in another regression

```
  lm(dat$detrended.data, rainfall)
```

Suppose my yield data is noisy (some years have same values) or I have missing year in between, what is the best way to detrend such data. For eg, if my data looks like this:

```
 dat1 <- structure(list(year = c(1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
                                 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), 
                         yield = c(1436.98, 1921.98, 1619.99, 1799.93, 1799.93, 1799.93, 1799.93, 2399.99, 2200.01, 2699.96, 2700, 2700.08, 
                                  2699.99, 2940.02, NA, 2639.99, NA, NA, 2700, 3000, 3120, 
                                  3000, 3000, 3180, 3180, 3180, 3240, 3060, 2400)), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -29L))

 with(dat1, plot(year, yield, type = "b", pch = 19))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, year is correlated with rainfall in many places -- either due to things like ENSO, AMO, PDO, IOD, etc., or due to anthropogenic climate change, or both.  That means that if you naively detrend without controlling for rainfall, you'll get a biased estimate in your regression on the detrended series.  Much better to run your regression with both year and rainfall in together.

Second, you should always choose your functional form via cross-validation.  The simplest way to do this would be with a smoothing spline, like the sort implemented by `mgcv` in R:

```
m <- gam(yield~s(year), data = dat1, method = "REML")
plot(m)
pred <- predict(m, newdata = data.frame(year = 1988:2016))

with(dat1, plot(year, yield, type = "b", pch = 19))      
lines(1988:2016, pred, col = "red")
```

[image]

the `gam` function is choosing smoothness to minimize something akin to a cross-validation criterion, though the formalism exploits the linkage between mixed modeling and penalized regression to use likelihood, rather than explicit cross-validation.

Of course, that dip at the end probably isn't due to the underlying secular trend, but rather due to factors specific to that year, like rainfall or temperature.  But if you treat the residuals from the red line as if they are the true detrended series, you'll be attenuating the estimated effect of whatever those correlated-in-time factors were.

Comment: The problem with this solution lies in how it neglects to model the serial correlation in the observations.  We also need to be cautious because it's obvious the data were fabricated, so these plots don't necessarily reveal much about the true structure of the data.  This also raises questions about the purpose: although the OP states this is for "regression," it's unclear what that's intended to mean.  Evidently a smoothing spline may be good for *interpolation* but it is nearly worthless for forecasting or even for understanding the underlying dynamics.

Comment: @whuber sure the detrending is second order.  OP's main problem is my first point.

Comment: Thank you. As I said, I want to understand the effect of rainfall on crop yield and in order to do that, I detrend the crop yield to remove any time trend that was caused because of improvement in technology. Once I detrend the data, I use the residuals and regress it against raiinfall to udnerstand the relatioship between rainfall and yield

Comment: @Crop89 technology is correlated with weather. Don't do a univariate detrending!